# Adding Attachments in ArcGIS 10.0 (problem - can’t find the instrument Enable Attachments)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, attachments

I want to create attachments to shp themes in ArcGIS (doc\pdf files, web-links). In the Help of ArcGIS I found the description of this operation:

[Adding attachments to features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m900000002000000)

[Add Attachments Tools (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000014v000000)

But before attachments can be added using this tool, they must first be enabled using the [Enable Attachments tool.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000153000000)

So, I have to find Enable Attachments tool in the Data Management Tools.
But I don't have this instrument in my ArcGIS Data Management Tools, so can’t add attachments (I tried to do it without use Enable Attachments tool, but in this case I just don't have "Open Attachment Manager button" which is needed for add attachment)).

Could you advise me, how I can find the instrument “Enable Attachments tool”?
Maybe I have to turn on something in the “properties”? Or this instrument has another name?

[image]

Comment: right click on the table in arccatalog. you don't mention the license you have. editor, arcinfo? You won't have enterprise gdb management tools at the viewer level.

Comment: I dont have the answer on enabling attachments in 10.0, but I can tell you that the attachment TOOLS (which you've mentioned) are new at 10.1. Thus you wont find that tool in 10.0. Whats new in 10.1: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Data_Management_toolbox/016w0000004n000000/

Comment: I have License Type: ArcInfo (I found it in "Help - About ArcMap")

Because in the "Adding attachments to features" they wrote:
"This topic applies to ArcGIS for Desktop Standard" 

I thought that it's should be possible to use this instrument with that license.

Comment: But if ArcGIS 10.0 just don't have these instrument - how it's possible to add attachments there? I wrote the inner Help page "Enabling attachments", they describe the same steps, but inform that: "This topic applies to ArcEditor and ArcInfo only"

So, with the License Type: ArcInfo - can I use this option? If not what should I do for obtain possibility to add attachments (in ArcGIS 10.0)?

Answer (score 4):

You can enable attachments with both ArcGis 10 & 10.1 :

- With 10.0, you have to open ArcCatalog, right-click the feature class to which you want to add attachments, point to Attachments, then click Create Attachments.
- With 10.1, you can do this via ArcCatalog, like explained previously OR via the "Enable Attachments" tool.

Regarding the licences levels :

- With ArcEditor and ArcInfo licences, you can enable and edit attachments.
- With ArcView, you can only read and open them.

Comment: The problem is - that when I do these steps (which I also found in Help), I don't have any option "Attachments", and "Create Attachments"

I put the image in my first post - what I see when open ArcCatalog and right-click the feature class.

Maybe I did something incorrectly?

Comment: From your screen shot it looks like you're using shapefiles. Attachments aren't supported on shapefiles. Try a featureclass inside a GDB or SDE

Comment: Nothing more to say than @KHibma !

Comment: Yes, you are right! I saved my shp in a GDB file - and found "Attachments" options. Thank you! My problem is solved.

Comment: Can someone guide me that how can I save a shape file to GDB using ArcCatalog please?

Comment: @azmuhak :
Into ArcCatalog, right click in the explorer.
New > File GDB. Then right-click on the GDB > Import > Feature Class